# how to use textField Extension to disable Copy and paste in swift ios

Tags: swift

I am trying to disable copy and paste functionality in a textField with the help of swift without using any separate cocoatouch class.
Can you suggest how to do it using Either keyboard extension or textfield extension.
Any response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom TextField as use as follows

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CustomeTextField: View {

    @State var textStr = ""


    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("This is textfield:")
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)

            TextFieldWrapperView(text: self.$textStr)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
        }
        .frame(height: 40)
    }
}


struct TextFieldWrapperView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> TFCoordinator {
        TFCoordinator(self)
    }
}

extension TextFieldWrapperView {


    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextFieldWrapperView>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }


    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {

    }
}

class TFCoordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var parent: TextFieldWrapperView

    init(_ textField: TextFieldWrapperView) {
        self.parent = textField
    }

    func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return canPerformAction(action: action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```